# Canvas animation ball moves only 5 times on mobile device

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, redux

I am building a simple game using react + redux to manage state of canvas objects such as a ball (x, y, ...etc).

The problem is that on mobile android Chrome the ball moves left when the green button is clicked but only a max of 5 times. On a desktop you can move the ball left all the way off the screen.

No idea how to solve this issue since I cant console.log on mobile chrome.

Game link: https://piqcel.herokuapp.com

Code: https://github.com/developer787/PiQCeL_DEMO

Thanks in advance!

Edit: The advice given by both users (Luke && brandaemon) are spot on and highly valuable and informative. Will update soom with a MCVE question soon.

Comment: Difficult to offer advice without an example demonstrating the problem. Way too much code in your repo to wade through to help solve the problem. Try coming up with a [Short Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the issue. You might solve it yourself just by going through that exercise.

Comment: Please include an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (that you can embed in your question if possible).  Few people are going to want to debug your entire application.

Comment: Thanks Luke for your quick response. The only way to reproduce the error is to visit the game link from your mobile phone and try to move the ball to the left all the way off the screen. About recreating the SSC ill read about that, interesting. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Luke and brandaemon I went and broke down the problem to its simplest form, and by doing so, discovered the issue that made me post here in the first place.

Thanks for the lesson guys, cheers!